# Angular: get Template URL from parent directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I understand that I can dynamically set a templateUrl base on an option DOM attribute `template-url="foo.html"` given the following code:

```
angular.module('foo').directive('parent', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           // code
       },
       templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
           return attrs.templateUrl || 'some/path/default.html'
       }
   }
});
```

However, I need to take this a step further and pass this string one level deeper, to a child directive.

Given this HTML:

**Usage in Main project**

`<parent parent-template="bar.html" child-template="foo.html"></parent>`

The child will not be exposed in most cases, so if `child-template` is set, it needs to implicitly replace `templateUrl` for all child `<child></child>` elements that are located in the parent `foo.html`.

The `require: '^parent'` attribute passes data from scope to scope, but I'm not seeing this available in `templateUrl` when it's declared.

**foo.html**

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<child ng-repeat="item in array"></child>
```

**Directives**

```
angular.module('foo').directive('parent', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           // code
       },
       templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
           return attrs.parentTemplate || 'some/path/default.html'
       },
       scope: {
          childTemplate: '=childTemplate'
       }
   }
})
.directive('child', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           // code
       },
       templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
           return ??? // parent.attribute.childTemplate? || 'some/path/default.html'
       },
       require: '^parent',
       scope: {
          childTemplate: '=childTemplate'
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: I just mad an edit to your code, please make sure that what I changed is correct (you named the second directive `parent`, just like the first one, I think that you wanted that to be named `child`). Thanks!

Comment: That's correct. Copy/paste mistake, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the `childTemplate` attached to the `child` directive's scope is overwriting that of the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

The old answer (see bellow) won't work because it's only possible to access the controller of the required directives inside the `link` functions, and the `templateUrl` function gets executed before the `link` functions.

Therefore the only way to solve this is to handle everything in the `templateUrl` function of the child directive. However [this function only takes 2 arguments: `tElement` and `tArgs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-).

So, we will have to find the element of the parent directive and access the attribute `child-template`. Like this:

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
.directive('parent', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       },
       transclude:true, 
       templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
           return attrs.parentTemplate || 'default.html'
       }
   }
})
.directive('child', function() { 
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       require:'^parent',
       templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
           //if jQuery is loaded the elem will be a jQuery element, so we can use the function "closest"
           if(elem.closest) 
              return elem.closest("parent").attr("child-template") || 'default.html';

           //if jQuery isn't loaded we will have to do it manually
           var parentDirectiveElem=elem; 
           do{
             parentDirectiveElem=parentDirectiveElem.parent();
           }while(parentDirectiveElem.length>0 && parentDirectiveElem[0].tagName.toUpperCase()!="PARENT");
           return parentDirectiveElem.attr("child-template") || 'default.html'; 
       }
   }
});
```

## [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wWHZG97CviYrUxmxjSOb)

## Old Answer

Since you are isolating the scope, you could try this, it's a bit hacky but I guess that it should work:

```
angular.module('foo').directive('parent', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       controller:  function($scope) {
           this.childTemplate=$scope.childTemplate;
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

       },       
       templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
           return attrs.parentTemplate || 'some/path/default.html'
       },
       scope: {
          childTemplate: '@'
       }
   }
})
.directive('child', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       require: '^parent',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentController) {
           if(parentController.childTemplate)
               element.data("childTemplate", parentController.childTemplate);
       },
       templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
           return elem.data("childTemplate") || 'some/path/default.html'
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: You may need to `$watch` the `childTemplate` of the child directive for this to work.

Comment: @dopatraman of the parent directive you mean, right? yep, that's a good idea, I'm going to update the code. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @dopatraman I've updated the code, the problem though, is that if the value of the attribute `childTemplate` changes in the parent, then I can watch for that change and update the controller... However, in the child I can't add a watcher because the property it's set in the controller of the parent, and you can only have watchers in the scope... Maybe I could try with observe, but that seems a bit too much, so I think that I will pass, since it seems quite unlikely that they op wants to account for that.

Comment: Thanks @Josep, I'm confused about your use of `parentController` inside the `child` directive's `link: fn()`.  Isn't `parentController` a reference to the controller of the `child` directive?  At least when testing out your code, that's how it's behaving for me.

Comment: @Brian `parentController` is a reference to the controller of the parent directive, notice that I'm using `require: '^parent'`, therefore in this case the controller that you get in the `link` function is the parent's controller.

Comment: @Brian I just realized that this won't work because the `templateUrl` function runs before the `link` function... Let me try something else.

Comment: Yup, I was thinking it wouldn't work per my comment in the original question about `templateUrl` being too late.

Comment: My concern is that it might only be possible in the `compile` function.  It would work, but obviously not ideal if it can be helped.

Comment: @Brian sorry, but since the templateUrl function runs before both the pre and post link functions... That means that by the time it runs you can't access the controller of the parent directive. Therefore your only option is to use the `jqLite` element and iterate up until you find the element of the parent directive and use the attribute from there. If you are using jQuery it's very easy because you can use `closest`... I will update this answer in the next hours and I will elaborate this. (Sorry, now I have to go play with my son ;) )

Comment: @Brian I just updated the answer, please let me know if that's what you wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my question, I was attempting to provide an override for the `templateUrl` of an off-the-shelf directive that didn't have one.  My original question doesn't mention this, however, I wanted to add this as a reference to others who may have forgotten, as I did.  Angular allows you to decorate directives and override their properties.

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('child', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    directive.templateUrl = 'path/to/custom.html';
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```